# linking to html file in /public

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a file 'maps.html' located in /public. I am loading up an index page with contents as follows: 
`<%= link_to 'redirect_click_here', 'maps.html' %>`. 
Application.html.erb takes care of the other necessary html elements for the page. 
The result of clicking that link is that I am sent to /map/maps.html.

This is slightly logical: the page hosting the link was in the 'map' controller. Still, I want to 'escape' the controller and access the public html file.

I realize that this is a kind of pointless request because I could just put the html file in app/views, but it's just for completion's sake that I put forth this request.

---

edit

One reason I want to include this file from the /public/ directory is that I don't want it to go through the asset pipeline and inherit the html document structure from application.html.erb. I am going to be including HTML files which include custom heads and I don't want to have to replace the contents of application.html.erb every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `'/maps.html'` in your link, so that it knows it is in the root public folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by

```
<%= link_to "Maps", "/your_project/maps.html" %>
```